# How could I read a binary file using fread?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
 typedef struct
{
    char*title;
    char* year;
    char* length; //in minutes
} record;

void write(record* list[])
{
    FILE* out=fopen("output.bin","a");
    if(!out)
    {
        printf("error"); exit(1);
    }else
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        {
            if(list[i]!=NULL)
                fwrite(list[i], sizeof(record), 1, out);
        }
        fclose(out);
    }
}
void read_back()
{
    FILE* input=fopen("output.bin","r");
    if(!input)
    {
        printf("error"); exit(1);
    }else
    {
        record* temp[1024];
        fread(temp,sizeof(record)*1024,1,input);


        fclose(input);
    }

}
```

How could I read the binary file using fread? Could anyone check if I did correct using fwrite? I want my read_back method to print the content in a struct (title, year etc).

Comment: In your `read_back` function you must allocate memory space for each record using the `malloc` function. BTW you probably should fopen with "w" (write) and not "a" (append). Also on some environnments (e.g. Windows) you need to use "rb" and "wb" instead of "r" and "w" with fopen for binary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`record` struct elements are defined as `pointer`s. `fread` cannot assign those pointers implicitly. For every element in the `record` struct, the values should be read explicitly and related values should be assigned after memory allocation through `malloc`.

`fwrite` will only write **memory addresses** in this way into the memory, since what `record` struct has only **pointers** inside.

There are two options

Define static array definitions like below

```
 typedef struct
{
    char title[256];
    char year[4];
    char length[8]; //in minutes
} record;
```

or

write `record` structure elements one by one by with their references.